# Socket API: bind error: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c, sockets

I'm new to c and I am trying to learn the sockets api, but I got this error: Socket operation on non-socket from Bind

Socket did not give an error

daytimeserv1.c:

```
#include "../holds/runp.h"
#include "../holds/wrapper.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int listenfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&listenfd, 0, sizeof(listenfd));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);

    Bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    for( ; ; ) {
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        Write(connfd, buff, strlen(buff));

        Close(connfd);
    }
}
```

Wrappers wrapper.c

```
#include "wrapper.h"

void err_sys(const char* x) {
    perror(x);
    exit(1);
}

int Socket(int family, int type, int protocol) {
    int n = socket(family, type, protocol);
    if (n < 0)
        err_sys("socket error");
    return(n);
}

void Bind(int fd, const struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t salen) {
    if(bind(fd, sa, salen) < 0)
        err_sys("bind error");
}
```

runp.h is just includes and constants

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!
(My build system is bazel if that helps at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are erasing the socket handle you just created via

```
memset(&listenfd, 0, sizeof(listenfd));
```

so you should remove it.
I guess what you actualy wanted to do is

```
memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
```